# Делегаты c#. Выполнение события нажатия кнопки мыши в другом классе

Tags: c#, wpf, делегаты

привет есть класс

```
public class Cell : Image
    {
        public event MouseButtonEventHandler LeftClick
        {
            add { MouseLeftButtonDown += value; }
            remove { MouseLeftButtonDown -= value; }
        }

        static Cell()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Cell), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Cell)));
        }

        public event MouseButtonEventHandler RightClick
        {
            add { MouseRightButtonDown += value; }
            remove { MouseRightButtonDown -= value; }
        }
    }
```

В другом классе я создал несколько экземпляров этого класса.
Но обработать нажатие мышки  хочу в отдельном классе. Как то можно туда перенести эти события. Я сделал 2 события

```
public event MouseButtonEventHandler LeftClick
            {
                add { MouseLeftButtonDown += value; }
                remove { MouseLeftButtonDown -= value; }
            }


            public event MouseButtonEventHandler RightClick
            {
                add { MouseRightButtonDown += value; }
                remove { MouseRightButtonDown -= value; }
            }
```

Но что то не получается.Как правильно. Я так понимаю наверно надо делегаты использовать но я что то не пойму как.

Comment: `myCell.LeftClick += otherObj.Method;`

Comment: Непонятно, что именно вам нужно. События для класса `Cell` дожны быть определены в классе `Cell`. А вот _подписаться_ на них вы можете где угодно.

Comment: ну я в классе classTwo создал 10 шт Cell.  И хочу в  ClassThee обрабатывать событие нажатия на них.

Comment: все разобрался  спасибо